# need text unwrap function

Tags: jquery, html

This is my code

```
$(document).each(function()
{
$('.imgContent span',this).unwrap();
});
```

html

```
<div>
     <h3>
         <span>$200</span>
      </h3>
</div>
```

I want remove span tag (NB- Remove span tag only  without content)

Answer (score 2):

What's with `$(document).each()`? Anyway, the following code should do the trick:

```
$(function() {
    $('h3 span').contents().unwrap(); 
});
```